# Running selenium tests for Django in gitlab-ci

Tags: python, selenium, gitlab-ci

Iam using latest firefox, xvfb

```
Django==1.8.2
selenium==2.45.0
```

and my gitlab-ci **job script**

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py test
```

before adding selenium tests django testcases passed without any error.
when i added selenium testcases to my project ci shell prompts for below error

```
raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

In my local system i can run both test without error. i think i am missing something in jobscript.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now `GitLab CI` is part of `GitLab`.
So, No to gitlab-ci job script. just adding ".gitlab-ci.yml" in project root directory will be enough

`.gitlab-ci.yml` file for my project:

```
Python 2.7:
    script:
    - export PY_EXE=python2.7
    - virtualenv env
    - source env/bin/activate
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - export DISPLAY=:10
    - python manage.py test
    except:
    - tags
```